# Cant get ManagedDTS version 15 folder even after installing SSDT for VS 2017

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-data-tools, sql-server-2019

I want to have SSDT for Visual studio 2017 to work with sql server 2019, so I will get manageddts version 15 at path
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS

I followed offline install specified here
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/previous-releases-of-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt-and-ssdt-bi?view=sql-server-ver16

Installation was successful but it does not create the required version of manageddt. Instead at path
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS

it created 3 folders
v4.0_11.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91
v4.0_12.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91
v4.0_13.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91

but I want
v4.0_15.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91
which is not being created.

Please help.

Comment: Pretty sure that you need SSDT in Visual Studio 2019 for support for SQL Server 2019 databases. The product in VS 2017 (unsurprisingly) supports versions released in 2017 and prior; it's not forward compatible.

Comment: oh ok thanks, we want to install SSDT on our servers, but dont want visual studio to be installed. Does there is shell version of vs 2019 present

Comment: *"Does there is shell version of vs 2019 present"* Sorry? *"we want to install SSDT on our server"* Why? Development should be on the developer's machines, not the host.

Comment: *"we want to install SSDT on our servers, but dont want visual studio to be installed"* You can't have one without the other. (What was)SSDT is only available as a Workload, "Data storage and processing", in Visual Studio (installed by modifying your installation of Visual Studio in the Visual Studio Installer); it's not a stand alone application.

Comment: we use dts runtime to execute SSIS packages stored in file server through microservice.

Comment: SSIS isn't SSDT. SSIS is completely separate and for development work is an *extension* to Visual Studio (not a workload like Data storage and processing). Are you asking about SSDT, or SSIS?

Comment: There is no longer a VS shell version of SSDT like there was in the SQL 2012 days. You need Visual Studio plus the SSIS project extension.

Comment: in microservice , we need to refer assembly at C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS\v4.0_15.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91\Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS.dll. which will be there after installing SSDT.

Comment: previously we were using :\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS\v4.0_11.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91\Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS.dll. for sql server 2012, now we have upgraded to SQL 2019

Comment: I have removed the <sql> tag since this isn't related to the SQL _language_.

Comment: That doesn't sound right; if it's the host that SQL Server is installed on, that dll will be there. Our SQL Server 2022 server, for example, doesn't even have SSMS installed and `GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS\v4.0_16.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91` is there. Simlarly, on a 2016 host, `GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS\v4.0_13.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91` is there. Without checking, I'm confident that `v4.0_15.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91` will be on our 2019 instance.

Comment: its app server and there  is no SQL server installed

Comment: So is this a deployed application? This all smells strongly of an [XY Problem](//xyproblem.info). The question, so far, has had nothing to do with SQL Server, SQl, or SSIS. I suggest you take a step back and explain the *real* problem, as it sounds like it has nothing to do with any of the technologies you've tagged or asked about here.

Comment: yes its deployed application

Comment: Sounds like the problem is the application then and, for some reason, when you build and publish it it isn't including the DLLs it needs. That's the *real* problem. That is what your question is really about.

Comment: So you are aware, what you've developed and what you're executing is a violation of the SQL Server licensing. You must license the server for SQL Server even if you're "just" using SSIS. In the event of an audit, this won't be treated as "they accidentally missed licensing this server", and your penance is to true up + buy some Azure. It will be "these people are stealing from us" and they'll come at your employer hard for license violations and that gets ugly.  So please, for the sake of your entire company, do not continue down this path.

Comment: In truth, if you do want to have an application start a SSIS package now a days (read in 2012 onwards), you should just call the appropriate procedures in the SSISDB.